# Push Notifications Stop working in parse.com android project

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on android application with parse.com. My Push notifications were working fine, but now suddenly in my project it stops working. I didn't change any thing in my project and on parse server. My Manifest file along with some code snippets are given below.

How can I trace the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.murgency"
    android:versionCode="40"
    android:versionName="1.8"
    >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.murgency.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.murgency.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="murgency.MUrgencyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
        <service android:name="com.appsee.AppseeBackgroundUploader" />

        <activity
            android:name="murgency.activities.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="open"
                    android:scheme="MUrgency" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="services.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="services.ContactService" />
        <receiver android:name="receiver.gps.GPSStartReceiver" />
        <service android:name="services.gps.GPSService" />
        <service
            android:name="services.GPSLoggerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Custom receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name="services.ParsePushReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.murgency.UPDATE_STATUS" />

            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- GCM -->
        <service
            android:name="services.GcmIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name="services.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.murgency.UPDATE_STATUS" />

                <category android:name="com.murgency" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
       <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Parse hosted service will be retired on January 28, 2017. So you have to migrate your app.

[See the Migration Url](http://parse.com/migration)

[Announcement from Parse](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/)